# Issue with pyldap and microsoft ldap

Tags: python, django, ldap

The issue is I have to connect a django develop with microsoft ldap, to create, modify, and authenticate users.

In the create exercise I have the next trouble, if I pass the attributes like this:

```
attrs = [
        ('objectclass', [b'user', b'top', b'person', b'organizationalPerson']),
        ('userPassword', [pwd.encode()]),
        ('displayName', [fullname.encode()]),
        ('name', fullname.encode()),
        ('givenName', [names_list[0].encode()]),
        ('sn', [lastnames_list[0].encode()]),', cn),
        ('userPrincipalName', userprincipalname),', samaccountname)
    ]
```

There's no problem and the user is created succesfully but disabled.

But, if I pass the parameters like this:

```
attrs = [
        ('objectclass', [b'user', b'top', b'person', b'organizationalPerson']),
        ('userPassword', [pwd.encode()]),
        ('displayName', [fullname.encode()]),
        ('name', fullname.encode()),
        ('givenName', [names_list[0].encode()]),
        ('sn', [lastnames_list[0].encode()]),', cn),
        ('userAccountControl', b'512'),
        ('userPrincipalName', userprincipalname),', samaccountname)
    ]
```

I get this error on the log:

> {'info': '0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n', 'desc': 'Server is unwilling to perform'}

I try with this line too:

```
('userAccountControl', str(NORMAL_ACCOUNT +  DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD).encode()),
```

And I get the same error.

I try with ldapadd on linux console too and I get the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually I have the same problem as you, would like to know how you have solved it if you did ofcourse

Comment: I finally solved. To get a user enabled or change a user's password, is fully necessary doing trough ldaps. To get this, I find a couple of useful links to get certificates from AD server and successfully stablish secure connection between the ad server and the django-app server http://pdhewaju.com.np/2016/04/08/installation-and-configuration-of-active-directory-certificate-services/    and     http://pdhewaju.com.np/2017/03/02/configuring-secure-ldap-connection-server-2016/   Sorry for the late answer, hope this help.